# ArduinoJson DynamicJsonDocument

Tags: arduino, arduino-esp8266

Wish you all good weekend! Simple newbie question: 
I'm trying to get some json data using ArduinoJson library. I have no idea how to get data from multidimension array.

Here is the json:

```
{"file":"1.png","time":"15000","data":[["test1","test2"],["test3","test4"],["test5","test6"]]}
```

here is the code:

```
// Allocate the JSON document
  // Use arduinojson.org/v6/assistant to compute the capacity.
  const size_t capacity = 3*JSON_ARRAY_SIZE(2) + JSON_ARRAY_SIZE(3) + JSON_OBJECT_SIZE(3)+63;
  DynamicJsonDocument doc(capacity);

  // Parse JSON object
  DeserializationError error = deserializeJson(doc, client);
  if (error) {
    Serial.print(F("deserializeJson() failed: "));
    Serial.println(error.c_str());
    return;
  }

  // Extract values
  Serial.println(F("Response:"));
  Serial.println(doc["file"].as<char*>());
  Serial.println(doc["time"].as<long>());
  Serial.println(doc["data"][0][0].as<char>());
  Serial.println(doc["data"][0][1].as<char>());
  Serial.println(doc["data"][1][0].as<char>());
  Serial.println(doc["data"][1][1].as<char>());
  Serial.println(doc["data"][2][0].as<char>());
  Serial.println(doc["data"][2][1].as<char>());
```

here is the result:

```
16:25:30.933 -> Response:
16:25:30.933 -> 1.png
16:25:30.933 -> 15000
16:25:30.933 -> 
16:25:30.933 -> 
16:25:30.933 -> 
16:25:30.933 -> 
16:25:30.933 -> 
16:25:30.933 -> 
16:25:30.933 -> *WM: freeing allocated params!
```

The question i how do I get to "data" subarrays ?

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but still... There are missing asterisks. You have to pass the pointer the same way you do at the `Serial.println(doc["file"].as<char*>());` row.

Replace the

```
Serial.println(doc["data"][0][0].as<char>());
Serial.println(doc["data"][0][1].as<char>());
Serial.println(doc["data"][1][0].as<char>());
Serial.println(doc["data"][1][1].as<char>());
Serial.println(doc["data"][2][0].as<char>());
Serial.println(doc["data"][2][1].as<char>());
```

with

```
Serial.println(doc["data"][0][0].as<char *>());
Serial.println(doc["data"][0][1].as<char *>());
Serial.println(doc["data"][1][0].as<char *>());
Serial.println(doc["data"][1][1].as<char *>());
Serial.println(doc["data"][2][0].as<char *>());
Serial.println(doc["data"][2][1].as<char *>());
```

I have tried to add it to your code and the result is

```
Response:
1.png
15000
test1
test2
test3
test4
test5
test6
```